# Custom navigation transition is instant instead of smooth as designed

Tags: css, reactjs

Every way I look at it, this navbar is supposed to transition in and out smoothly just like the hamburger menu, but its instant no matter what I change, I hope I'm just not crazy. Here is the css and html down below.

```
<header>
        {/* Desktop navigation menu */}
        <nav className="desktop-menu">
          {/* Your navigation links here */}
          <a href="/">Home</a>
          <a href="/projects">Projects</a>
          <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </nav>

        {/* Mobile navigation menu (hamburger menu) */}
        <div className="mobile-menu">
            <label className='menu-toggle' >
                <input type='checkbox' onClick={toggleMobileMenu}/>
            </label>
          {/* <button className="menu-toggle" onClick={toggleMobileMenu}>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </button> */}
          {/* Conditional rendering of mobile menu */}
          {showMobileMenu && (
            <nav className={`sidebar ${showMobileMenu ? 'active' : ''}`}>
              <a className='mobile-link' href="/">Home</a>
              <a className='mobile-link' href="/projects">Projects</a>
              <a className='mobile-link' href="/contact">Contact</a>
            </nav>
          )}
        </div>
      </header>
```

CSS

```
/* HomePage.css */

/* Apply default styles */
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* Homepage container */
.homepage-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}


header {
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}



nav a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}


main {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}


.project-cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 20px;
}


.project-card {
    background-color: var(--foreground);
    color: var(--background);
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.project-card a {
    color: var(--background);
}


footer {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

:root {
    --bar-width: 50px;
    --bar-height: 8px;
    --hamburger-gap: 6px;
    --foreground: #333;
    --background: white;
    --hamburger-margin: 5px;
    --animation-timing: 200ms ease-in-out;
    --hamburger-height: calc(var(--bar-height) * 3 + var(--hamburger-gap) * 2)
}



@media (min-width: 769px) {

    /* Hide mobile menu on desktop */
    .mobile-menu {
        display: none;
    }
}

/* Media query for mobile devices */
@media (max-width: 767px) {

    main {
        align-items: center;
    }


    header {
        background-color: transparent;
        padding: 1.5rem;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        /* Align navigation and hamburger menu */
        align-items: center;
        /* Center vertically */
    }

    .project-cards {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .desktop-menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .menu-toggle {
        --x-width: calc(var(--hamburger-height) * 1.41421356237);
        display: none;
        flex-flow: column;
        gap: var(--hamburger-gap);
        width: max-content;
        position: fixed;
        top: var(--hamburger-margin);
        left: var(--hamburger-margin);
        z-index: 10;
        cursor: pointer
    }
    
    .menu-toggle:has(input:checked) {
        --foreground: white;
        --background: #333;
    }
    
    .menu-toggle::before,
    .menu-toggle::after,
    .menu-toggle input {
        content: "";
        width: var(--bar-width);
        height: var(--bar-height);
        background-color: var(--foreground);
        border-radius: 9999px;
        transform-origin: left center;
        transition: opacity var(--animation-timing), width var(--animation-timing),
            rotate var(--animation-timing), translate var(--animation-timing),
            background-color var(--animation-timing);
    }
    
    .menu-toggle input {
        appearance: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        outline: none;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    
    
    .menu-toggle:has(input:checked)::before {
        rotate: 45deg;
        width: var(--x-width);
        translate: 0 calc(var(--bar-height) / -2);
    
    }
    
    .menu-toggle:has(input:checked)::after {
        rotate: -45deg;
        width: var(--x-width);
        translate: 0 calc(var(--bar-height) / 2);
    }
    
    .menu-toggle input:checked {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0;
    }
    



    .sidebar {
        transition: translate var(--animation-timing);
        translate: -100%;
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        padding-top: calc(var(--hamburger-height) + var(--hamburger-margin) + 1rem);
        background-color: var(--foreground);
        color: var(--background);
        max-width: 10rem;
        min-height: 100vh;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .menu-toggle:has(input:checked)+.sidebar {
        translate: 0;
    }


    .menu-toggle {
        display: flex;
    }

    .mobile-menu nav a {
        display: block;
        color: var(--background);
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

I've tried changing the way I transition to transform, and I tried it without the css variables.